# Python rank: give negative rank to negative numbers

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have a basic set of data like:

```
ID Value
A  0.1
B  0.2
C  -0.1
D  -0.01
E  0.15
```

If we use data.rank() we get the result:

```
ID Value
A  3
B  5
C  1
D  2
E  4
```

But i want to have so that the negative values result in an negative rank instead such as:

```
ID Value
A  1
B  3
C  -2
D  -1
E  2
```

Basically rank give the negative values an negative rank while the postive values get a positive rank but instead of 1 to 5 we get 1 to 3 and -1 to -2.
Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: Your rank values are incorrect. How do you have the positive numbers [0.1, 0.2, 0.15] ranked as [2, 3, 1]?

Comment: The Positive Rank doesn't seem to be correct. Can you edit this? Or Confirm that it is indeed correct

Comment: thanks for the comment guys, have edited it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method similar to the concat answer, but not as compact:

```
import pandas as pd

A = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
B = [-1, 1, 3, -2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': A, 'value': B})

pos = df.where(df['value'] >= 0)['value'].rank()
neg = df.where(df['value'] < 0)['value'].rank(ascending=False)
pos.update(-neg)

df['rank'] = pos
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ID  value  rank
0  A     -1  -1.0
1  B      1   1.0
2  C      3   2.0
3  D     -2  -2.0
```

Edit: I noticed that the negative rank did not follow the order you specified in your post, so I added "ascending=False" in rank() to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Rank your positive values and negative values separately and then `concat` them:

```
>>> pd.concat([df[df["Value"].gt(0)].rank(),df[df["Value"].lt(0)].mul(-1).rank().mul(-1)]).sort_index()

    ID  Value
0  1.0    1.0
1  2.0    3.0
2 -1.5   -2.0
3 -1.5   -1.0
4  3.0    2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the specific example described, but not as a general solution

Comment: How not? It isn't referencing anything specific to your solution except for the column name.

Comment: No idea why, but when running on another dataset it gives wrong values

Answer (score 0):

Think outside the box & sort your values.

```
# create your dummy data
data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('ABCDE'), 'Value':[0.1,0.2,-0.1,-0.01,0.15]})

# sort the data so that we can use of the cumsum (and vectorize the operation)
data = data.sort_values('Value')

# Cumulartive sum of the booleans for the  positive values
# Minus the the inverse sum of the booleans of the negative values
data['RANK'] = (data['Value']>=0).cumsum() - (data['Value']<0)[::-1].cumsum() 

# Sort the values back to the original state ...    
data.sort_values('ID')


     ID     Value   RANK
0     A      0.10    1
1     B      0.20    3
2     C     -0.10   -2
3     D     -0.01   -1
4     E      0.15    2
```